# batch program to send values from one .bat file one one system to another bat file in another system

Tags: windows, batch-file

i looked for a code over  the net and what i could get close to, was to ping two systems using batch program.
the snippet is
PING 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 60000 >NUL
but i am not quite sure if it serves the actual purpose.
the values that are being sent have to be automatically be used by the second batch program

Comment: check `waitfor` command - http://ss64.com/nt/waitfor.html - I think this is exactly what you want

Answer (score 0):

`PING 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 60000 >NUL` is only a kind of timeout which delays the execution of the next code line by 60000 milliseconds. It has nothing to do with communication between two bat files.